# OpenGL ES20 - Wavefront -> glDrawElements -> no pyramid, but a weird shape?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, wavefront

EDIT 2:

Solution: Copy paste mistake: sent color buffer as position buffer.

---

Parsing my .obj (wavefront) which represents a pyramid, triangulating where its necessary, passing it all into buffers. The buffers look as follows:

Vertex Buffer:

```
private FloatBuffer mPositionBuffer = null;
// from looping through buffer + print:
#0 = -0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#3 = 0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#6 = 0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#9 = -0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#12 = 0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#15 = 0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#18 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
#21 = 0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#24 = -0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#27 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
#30 = -0.5, 0.0, -0.5
#33 = -0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#36 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
#39 = -0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#42 = 0.5, 0.0, 0.5
#45 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
```

Color Buffer:

```
private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer = null;
#0 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#4 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#8 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#12 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#16 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#20 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#24 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#28 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#32 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#36 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#40 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#44 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#48 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#52 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#56 = 1, 1, 1, 1
#60 = 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Normal Buffer:

```
private FloatBuffer mNormalBuffer = null;



#0 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
#3 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
#6 = 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
#9 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
#12 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
#15 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
#18 = 0.5, 1.0, 0.0
#21 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
#24 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
#27 = 0.5, 1.0, 0.0
#30 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
#33 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
#36 = 0.5, 1.0, 0.0
#39 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
#42 = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
#45 = 0.5, 1.0, 0.0
```

Indices Buffer:

```
private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer = null;
#0 = 0, 1, 3
#3 = 1, 2, 3
#6 = 4, 5, 6
#9 = 7, 8, 9
#12 = 10, 11, 12
#15 = 13, 14, 15
```

When combining vertices + faces in my mind, it equals a pyramid, just like it's supposed to. Simple model.
I'm drawing it as follows:

```
// data above are put in these buffers





    mColorBuffer.position(0);
    mNormalBuffer.position(0);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);
    mPositionBuffer.position(0);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_POSITION), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mColorBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_POSITION));

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_COLOR), 4, GLES20.GL_BYTE, false,
                0, mColorBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_COLOR));

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_NORMAL), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, mNormalBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.A_NORMAL));

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mShader.getGLLocation(BaseShader.U_MVPMATRIX), 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, mIndexBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);
```

But there is an object, which does not really look like a pyramide and is "shaky" as a result, i.e. if I translate it (without rotation, but the code looks like this (and is executed before the drawing-one):

```
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTranslation[0], mTranslation[1], mTranslation[2]);
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, mScale[0], mScale[1], mScale[1]);

    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotation[0], 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotation[1], 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotation[2], 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
```

Looks to me as if the indices are not transmitted properly? Only one of the pyramid's side is being drawn unfortunately.

Do I have to use other values for the glDrawElements function? If needed, I can post either a screenshot or screencapture of the translation animation. Thank you very much for any help!

EDIT:

In case this has anything to do with it:

I'm calling these:

```
    GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure, but it looks like a culling problem(do you ever set the culling? i dont know what is the default value). ...Also are you sure that GL_TRIANGLE_FAN is what your indices are arranged like? looks more like a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP arrangement.

EDIT : 
Now that i look at your vertices, I think that GL_TRIANGLES is what you need to use, so i was wrong the first time. Sorry for that.

Now lets look at an example of how different index arrangements work : lets take the simplest 3d form , a tetrahedron. Also lets use some really simple coordinates, you can pick those as you wish:

```
(0,0,0, // point0
,1,0,0, // point1
,0,1,0, // point2
,0,0,1) // point3
```

so that will give us a 12 long array with 4 sets of coordinates, now here is how our indices would look if we're using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP:

```
(0,1,2,3,0,1)
```

which means that we draw our first triangle - (0,1,2) and then add one more next to it with (3) , then go back to (0) and so on.

and if we're using GL_TRIANGLES the same would look like :

```
(0,1,2,
2,1,3,
3,1,0,
0,2,3)
```

as you can see with GL_TRIANGLES we're just listing triangles one after another without order. (I've picked those to be counter clock-wise not sure if this is the default cull value)

In your case it seems that you have duplicate vertices so the walls can have proper normals and look flat. So you have separate vertices for each wall even if they coincide with the next one. Again, my advice is to leave Just one triangle - three vertices, three indices, and add more one by one until you get your full figure.

Comment: Hi, now that you mention it, I've (finally) read the difference between fan and strip and you're right, a pyramid (with a "floor") can probably not be displayed as a fan. But I don't think that's the whole problem. I've tried around with culling, but I'm unsure which option exactly is the right one, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: if looking at the wall vertices 1,2 and 3 (in that order) are counter-clockwise thats GL_FRONT, otherwise its GL_BACK. To enable culling call : 'glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); glCullFace(GL_FRONT);'

Comment: .. errr, actually that's not correct, you can specify the direction to be CW or CCW . Here i found a useful article that includes detailed explanation  about cull constants [link](http://blog.db-in.com/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-2/)

Comment: So I've changed it to TRIANGLE_STRIP, but no real improvement happened.. also enabled GL_CULL_FACE, but this did not help neither.. Drawing the same pyramid structure (with the vertices/normals I've posted above) with glDrawArrays I see a pyramid, but with only one side missing. I believe this is because I can't add indices to glDrawArrays? Is there a way how I can fix/workaround this?

Comment: I'm not a fan of glDrawArrays, it's good to ave control over your indices. If i were you, I'd start by drawing a single triangle and keep then adding to it until i get the full pyramid. That is kinda how TRIANGLE_STRIP works anyway. Otherwise you might just go for GL_TRIANGLES (much simpler to comprehend). PS. why do you have so many vertices? did you come with those by yourself?

Comment: Ok my mistake was that I've sent the color buffer as position buffer. Copypasta mistake... took me a couple days to see it. Thanks anyways!